# how to limit the user to enter only 10 characters in the console using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, system.in

I want to limit the user to enter only 10 integer in the consol "System.in" i can do it using While but i want a way to do it using stream from java 8

The problem whit the code i did is that the user keep entering caracters until he click enter and then i took only 10 first int 
what i want is to limit him from typing only 10 times

hope that i was clear (I have a bad english)

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
  int[] test = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).limit(10).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

} catch (IOException E) {
}
```

Comment: You cannot limit the number of characters the user enters on the command line - this happens before Java even sees the data. If you do it line by line that would work.

Comment: so the only way is to put the scanner in a while and limit the iterations to 10 ??

Comment: `IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObject(__ -> //read the line//)`

Comment: IntStream.range(1, 10) i think will allow me to work only with numbers from 1 to 10 but here i have a ranger from 1 to 1000 but only 10 int

Comment: I think I will use the traditional way

Comment: I don't understand your comment - the `1, 10` will cause the loop to iterate 10 times (actually 9 times, should be `0, 10`). It has no bearing on your input or the numbers you want to work with. That's what the `__` means - ignore the argument and do something unrelated.

Comment: Ahhh ook thank you i will try it

Comment: What do you mean with “traditional way”? There is no way to stop the user from entering data you’re not reading. It doesn’t matter which API you use.

Comment: I too am curious: How would you imagine that you would be able to stop the user from hitting the keyboard??

Comment: sorry guys maybe it's just because my english is so bad that why you didn't get my idea ... well what i did is just a loop from 0 to 10 and inside the loop i used 'input.nextInt()' so i limited the user to enter only 10 integer after the last integer I display the result immediately